# Выбор контактов как в Gmail

Tags: html, css, javascript

При выборе адресата выпадают все возможные другие адресаты с похожим инициалом.

Какими средствами это делается?

Можно пример или ссылку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делается это при помощи поля ввода (тэг `input`, но не обязательно с ним) с автодополнением. В интернете много подобных плагинов для jQuery ([раз](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete), [два](http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/demo/), [три](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/jquery/74713/) и [т.д.](http://www.google.ru/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+autocomplete+plugin)).

Если хочется реализовать что-то подобное самостоятельно, то в идеале подобная вещь реализуется при помощи префиксного дерева ([trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)).

Comment: Сделал на javascript.